# LaTeX citation undefined

Tags: citing

I am trying to add a citation to my paper but keep getting the same error:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Gorantla2023DynaQ' on page 6 undefined on input line 143.
```

In the .tex file it is represented as follows: "The code implemented was inspired by ?."

I used the following to create a new citation in the .bib file:

```
@misc{Gorantla2023DynaQ,
  author = {Ashok Gorantla},
  title = {Extending Q-Learning With Dyna-Q for Enhanced Decision-Making},
  year = {2023},
  howpublished = {\url{https://dzone.com/articles/extending-q-learning-with-dyna-q#:~:text=Update%20Rule%20%2D%20Q%2Dvalues%20are,the%20importance%20of%20future%20rewards}},
  publisher = {Dzone}
}
```

I am new to LaTeX so I only have tried to change the @misc, but this did not solve the issue.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/77976649/2777074

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SX! This is the right place for questions like yours and it most likely someone here can help you. To understand your problem and help us get you an answer it would help if you provide a Minimal Working Example MWE. A short tex code starting with `\documentclass{...` and ending in `\end{document}` that recreates the problem.

Comment: The URL seems needlessly complicated. I suggest you simplify it `\url{https://dzone.com/articles/extending-q-learning-with-dyna-q}`. Incidentally, you should encase the words "Q-Learning" and "Dyna-Q" in the `title` field in curly braces, to prevent BibTeX from changing them to lowercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
\cite{Gorantla2023DynaQ}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

The bib file is same to you provieded. I run the command below, and I get the right PDF output.

```shell
pdflatex main
bibtex main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect the problem was the `%` characters in the OPs file. In that case, it's the loading of the xurl package that fixes this? Would using `url={...}` in the bib file also work?

Comment: @EladDen Due to the uncertainty regarding all of OP's code, it is difficult to determine the source of the problem. I noticed that OP used the `\url` command, which requires the `url` package. To enhance aesthetics, I opted to utilize the `xurl` package, which can break line at any point in the url.

Comment: @EladDen - The `plain` bibliography style is so ancient that it doesn't know about a field called `url`. Switching to the `plainnat` style, in turn, would enable proper processing of `url` fields.